# Migrating All Data From 3 Year Old MacBook Pro to Brand New MacBook Pro Using Leopard and Time Machine

Tags: mac, macbook, time-machine, migration

I've been using a MacBook Pro for about 3 years - and when Leopard came out I upgraded my computer and set up a Time Machine drive.

Now 3 years have rolled around I've bought a brand new 17" MacBook Pro. I'd like to migrate ALL my data using my Time Machine backup.

I upgraded my hard drive on my older MacBook Pro (about 6 months ago) and successfully used Time Machine to migrate all my data using Time Machine and a fresh install of Leopard.

Can I do the same migration steps to my new machine?

I'm worried that hardware differences (and drivers) will cause issues during the time machine restoration.

Any help is greatly appreciated,

-CVertex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can - the steps will be near identical to what you did when you did it with Leopard. That said when you first set up your new MacBook Pro it gives you the option of moving data from the Time Machine backup without requiring a re-install.

Mac OS X 10.6 will include all the drivers necessary to run both your new MacBook Pro and the old MacBook Pro if it were loaded on either or. (So in this case the worry about drivers is for naught as it's all Apple supplied hardware and drivers anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Using the migration assistant on your new Mac hook up the two boxes with firewire cable and either boot your old Mac up in Target Mode (hold down 't' on reboot or choose target mode in system preferences )
OR
Restore from your TM backup - same result.

The new Macbook will come with the OS and all drivers installed anyway, so that won't be a problem